# Datepicker not working in jquery loaded ajax modal window on codeigniter

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, codeigniter

I am trying to edit my database table using jquery loaded ajax modal. and when i trigger the edit form using ajax, the bootstrap datepicker and selct2 plugin is not working but the same datepicker and select2 plugin is working fine inside the page. and i am also trying to bind the jquery inside the modal but its not working too. here is my code for the ajax loaded popup form.

```html
<?php 
$edit_data      =   $this->db->get_where('staff' , array('staff_id' => $param2) )->result_array();
foreach ( $edit_data as $row):
?>
    
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="panel panel-primary">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <div class="panel-title" >
                    <i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i>
                    <?php echo get_phrase('edit_staff');?>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                
                <?php echo form_open(base_url() . 'index.php?admin/staffs/do_update/'.$row['staff_id'] , array('autocomplete'=>'off','target'=>'_top'));?>
                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <label class="col-sm-4 control-label"><?php echo get_phrase('staff_name');?></label>
                        <div class="col-sm-8">
                            <div class="inputer">
                                <div class="input-wrapper">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="program_name" value="<?php echo $row['name']; ?>">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <label class="col-sm-4 control-label"><?php echo get_phrase('date_of_birth_');?> <i class="ion-android-calendar"></i></label>
                        <div class="col-sm-8">
                            <div class="inputer">
                                <div class="input-wrapper">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control bootstrap-daterangepicker-basic" id="datepicker" name="dob" value="<?php echo $row['dob']; ?>">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <label class="col-sm-4 control-label"><?php echo get_phrase('address');?> </label>
                        <div class="col-sm-8">
                            <div class="inputer">
                                <div class="input-wrapper">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="address" value="<?php echo $row['address']; ?> ">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div><!--.form-group-->

                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <label class="col-sm-4 control-label"><?php echo get_phrase('phone');?> </label>
                        <div class="col-sm-8">
                            <div class="inputer">
                                <div class="input-wrapper">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="phone" value="<?php echo $row['phone']; ?>">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div><!--.form-group-->

                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <label class="col-sm-4 control-label"><?php echo get_phrase('email');?> </label>
                        <div class="col-sm-8">
                            <div class="inputer">
                                <div class="input-wrapper">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="email" value="<?php echo $row['email']; ?>">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div><!--.form-group-->

                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <label class="col-sm-4 control-label"><?php echo get_phrase('sex');?></label>
                        <div class="col-sm-8">
                            <select name="sex" style="width:100%;">
                                <option value="1" <?php if($row['sex'] == '1')echo 'selected';?>>
                                    <?php echo get_phrase('male');?>
                                </option>
                                <option value="2" <?php if($row['sex'] == '2')echo 'selected';?>>
                                    <?php echo get_phrase('female');?>
                                </option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div><!--.form-group-->

                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <label class="col-sm-4 control-label"><?php echo get_phrase('department');?></label>
                        <div class="col-sm-8">
                            <select name="department_id" class="chosen-select">
                                <?php 
                                        $departments = $this->db->get('department')->result_array();
                                        foreach($departments as $row2):
                                    ?>
                                        <option value="<?php echo $row2['department_id'];?>"
                                            <?php if($row['department_id'] == $row2['department_id'])echo 'selected';?>>
                                                <?php echo $row2['name'];?>
                                        </option>
                                    <?php
                                    endforeach;
                                    ?>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div><!--.form-group-->

                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <label class="col-sm-4 control-label"><?php echo get_phrase('designation');?> </label>
                        <div class="col-sm-8">
                            <div class="inputer">
                                <div class="input-wrapper">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="post" value="<?php echo $row['post']; ?>">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div><!--.form-group-->

                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <label class="col-sm-4 control-label"><?php echo get_phrase('is_teacher');?></label>
                        <div class="col-sm-8">
                            <select name="is_teacher" style="width:100%;">
                                <option value="1" <?php if($row['is_teacher'] == '1')echo 'selected';?>>
                                    <?php echo get_phrase('Yes');?>
                                </option>
                                <option value="2" <?php if($row['is_teacher'] == '0')echo 'selected';?>>
                                    <?php echo get_phrase('No');?>
                                </option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div><!--.form-group-->
                    <br/><br/>
                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <div class="col-sm-offset-3 col-sm-5">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i> <?php echo get_phrase('edit_staff');?></button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<?php
endforeach;
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
   $("#datepicker").FormsPickers.init();
</script>
```

and below is my code for generating ajax loaded popup ..

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
 function showAjaxModal(url)
 {
  // SHOWING AJAX PRELOADER IMAGE
  jQuery('#modal_ajax .modal-body').html('<div style="text-align:center;margin-top:200px;"><img src="assets/images/preloader.gif" /></div>');
  
  // LOADING THE AJAX MODAL
  jQuery('#modal_ajax').modal('show', {backdrop: 'true'});
  
        
  // SHOW AJAX RESPONSE ON REQUEST SUCCESS
  $.ajax({
   url: url,
   success: function(response)
   {
    jQuery('#modal_ajax .modal-body').html(response);
   }
  });
 }
 </script>
```

```html
 <!-- (Ajax Modal)-->
    <div class="modal fade" id="modal_ajax">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title"><?php echo $system_name;?></h4>
                </div>
                
                <div class="modal-body" style="height:500px; overflow:auto;">
                
                    
                    
                </div>
                
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                </div>
                
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

this is the include_buttom.php ...

```html
<script src="assets/globals/plugins/pnikolov-bootstrap-colorpicker/dist/js/bootstrap-colorpicker.min.js"></script>
 <script src="assets/globals/plugins/minicolors/jquery.minicolors.min.js"></script>
 <script src="assets/globals/plugins/bootstrap-daterangepicker/daterangepicker.js"></script>
 <script src="assets/globals/plugins/clockface/js/clockface.js"></script>
 
 <script src="assets/globals/plugins/chosen/chosen.jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="assets/globals/plugins/selectize/dist/js/standalone/selectize.min.js"></script>
 <script src="assets/globals/plugins/multiselect/js/jquery.multi-select.js"></script>
 <script src="assets/globals/plugins/quicksearch/dist/jquery.quicksearch.min.js"></script>
 <script src="assets/globals/plugins/bootstrap-select/dist/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>
 <script src="assets/globals/plugins/jasny-bootstrap/dist/js/jasny-bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 
 <script src="assets/globals/plugins/jquery-validation/dist/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
 <script src="assets/globals/plugins/twitter-bootstrap-wizard/jquery.bootstrap.wizard.min.js"></script>
 
 <!-- PLUGINS INITIALIZATION AND SETTINGS -->
 <script src="assets/globals/scripts/forms-select.js"></script>
 <script src="assets/globals/scripts/forms-pickers.js"></script>
 <script src="assets/globals/scripts/forms-wizard.js"></script>
 
 <!-- END PLUGINS INITIALIZATION AND SETTINGS -->
 <!-- PLEASURE -->
 <script src="assets/globals/js/pleasure.js"></script>
 <!-- ADMIN 1 -->
 <script src="assets/admin1/js/layout.js"></script>
 <script>
 $(document).ready(function () {
  Pleasure.init();
  Layout.init();
  
  FormsPickers.init();
  FormsSelect.init();
  Index.init();
 });
 </script>
```

Comment: where is datepicker script ?

Comment: datepicker script is loaded inside the page itself .... on include_buttom.php

Answer (score 0):

this is the include_buttom.php ...

```html
<script src="assets/globals/plugins/pnikolov-bootstrap-colorpicker/dist/js/bootstrap-colorpicker.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/globals/plugins/minicolors/jquery.minicolors.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/globals/plugins/bootstrap-daterangepicker/daterangepicker.js"></script>
<script src="assets/globals/plugins/clockface/js/clockface.js"></script>
 
<script src="assets/globals/plugins/chosen/chosen.jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/globals/plugins/selectize/dist/js/standalone/selectize.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/globals/plugins/multiselect/js/jquery.multi-select.js"></script>
<script src="assets/globals/plugins/quicksearch/dist/jquery.quicksearch.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/globals/plugins/bootstrap-select/dist/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/globals/plugins/jasny-bootstrap/dist/js/jasny-bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 
<script src="assets/globals/plugins/jquery-validation/dist/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/globals/plugins/twitter-bootstrap-wizard/jquery.bootstrap.wizard.min.js"></script>
 
<!-- PLUGINS INITIALIZATION AND SETTINGS -->
<script src="assets/globals/scripts/forms-select.js"></script>
<script src="assets/globals/scripts/forms-pickers.js"></script>
<script src="assets/globals/scripts/forms-wizard.js"></script>
 
<!-- END PLUGINS INITIALIZATION AND SETTINGS -->
<!-- PLEASURE -->
<script src="assets/globals/js/pleasure.js"></script>
<!-- ADMIN 1 -->
<script src="assets/admin1/js/layout.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
 Pleasure.init();
 Layout.init();
  
 FormsPickers.init();
 FormsSelect.init();
 Index.init();
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually you calling the assest in wrong path. Means you are missing `base_url()` word in your `src` URL

Your code should be

```
<script src="<?php echo base_url() ?>assets/globals/plugins/pn...
```

Comment: this is also working on my actual page .. the datepicker and select 2 is working inside the url loaded page but the same datepicker and select2 is not working inside the ajax loaded pop up form.

Comment: check the ID 's of datepickers

Comment: is there any problem in my code .. what you mean by ID's can you explain me further about it

Answer (score 0):

## 1.

first of all give exact path to all of your assets as

```
<script src="<?php echo base_url() ?>assets/globals/plugins/pnikolov-bootstrap-colorpicker/dist/js/bootstrap-colorpicker.min.js"></script>
```

or

```
<script src="<?php echo base_url('assets/globals/plugins/pnikolov-bootstrap-colorpicker/dist/js/bootstrap-colorpicker.min.js') ?>"></script>
```

## 2.

what following codes do at your include_button page??

FormsPickers.init();

FormsSelect.init();

you are initializing FormsPicker with selector ID which can be multiple since you are looping there. change that selector to class name.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $("#datepicker").FormsPickers.init();
</script>
```

to

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(".class_name").FormsPickers.init();
</script>
```

## 3.

Best initialize choosen and datepicker by yourself as following in your  ajax loaded popup form

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(".choosen_class").chosen();
   $(".datepicker_class').datepicker();
</script>
```

by doing these i hope your problem should be solved. If still problem persist, do ask us :)

Comment: sorry for the late reply @puncoz ... actually i am implemented with new way but still it didn't work ... please view my answer

Comment: implemented new ways means??? could you share what you are trying to do. then we may help you on that